# I have problem in getting data perfectly in adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

Cconsider one CSV file with employee details and attendance marking attendance with 0 and 1. For example, 1 indicates the employee is present, 0 indicates employee is absent. My problem is to get the working date of employee if they are present (1). It should be the same day where the employee is absent (0). It should be next working day by reading the previous row.

| emp id | working | working day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 11/14/2022 |
| 123 | 0 | 11/15/2022 |
| 123 | 1 | 11/14/2022 |

I have tried using data flow in ADF, but it is not getting. Please provide solution for me in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate the csv data in data factory we have to use [Data Flow activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) in **Azure data factory**

I reproduce your scenario in my environment please follow below steps to get issue resolved:

I took one **sample file as source** in `Data flow activity` similar to data you provided as below (assuming you don't have date values when employee is absent):

[image]

Then I took windows transformation activity **over emp id and sort by emp id** and created windows column **working date** with updating Date based on previous row value with expression:

```
lag(addDays({working day}, 1),1)
```

[image]

Windows transformation data preview:

[image]

Now I took derived column transformation **to get date working date of employee if they are present or absent**. I am updating the column working day if working is 0 then value should be working date else value will working day.

```
iif(working==0,{working date},{working day})
```

[image]

Derived column transformation data preview:

[image]

Now with select activity delete unnecessary columns and store the data in sink.

Select transformation data preview:
[image]

Comment: Tq you very much.